# Very slow PDF printing on Ubuntu 14.04 => Unusable

Tags: 14.04, printing, pdf

I try to use Ubuntu 14.04.3 (Trusty Tahr) in a company environment (I personally have used Linux for the past 15 years). But I have a big problem when I try to **print PDF files**, like presentation (text and images). **It is very very slow...** It is on a printer network (Kyocera, Brother, ...), and the network is not the problem.

For a file ~5 Mo.. it take **more than five minutes to print eight pages**. It is unusable!

I tried Adobe Reader, Evince, qpdfview, and Okular. Only Adobe Reader is faster, but also have another problem.

I googled many things, but I didn't find the solution.

Comment: Whats your printer driver? You can see the drivers in your system with the URL http://localhost:631/printers/

Comment: Maybe it's the buffer issue to the printer?

Comment: @A.B.  It use socket on port 9100 with a PPD file (Postscript) - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kyocera/Kyocera-KM-C2520

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes sorry is Megabytes, is not a big big file

Comment: @P.-H.Lin I don't think so because it work perfectly on Windows.  I suspect pdftops CUPS problem..

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the slow printer problem in my dual booting (14.04 & 16.04) desktop. The problem is there with evince or lpr when printing a multiple page pdf. Luckily I found a workaround in okular, which prints at regular speed.